# Ideas on how to pass data from URL to a C# application?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, parameter-passing

Secnario: The user is given a link to download an application, the link also contains some parameters the application needs to function, such as an ID for example https://websitedownload?id=1234

The website distributes an MSI that downloads a C# application.

However, the C# application needs access to the 1234 parameter. What are some ways we can give it access?

Comment: I'd be looking for ways to bundle a user specific config file with the msi, or at least send the msi in a zip file with the config file. Then ask the user to find and select the config file on first launch.

Comment: This website can re-package the MSI on each download per parameter. And no, it's not a single one-function action (or even from Javascript).

Comment: If the MSI is *not signed* then it can be trivially unpacked, an internal file can be modified (later to be read by the application), and it can be repacked. 7Zip is one tool that can open MSI archives. Re-signing the MSI (if needed), altering the program to read the config, and providing a (new) checksum for user verification are additional steps. Everyone who download the given MSI would then also have the embedded value (as well as everyone they shared said MSI with).